# WebLogic and Java EE connection refusal

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, netbeans, weblogic

I have a problem with my WebLogic Oracle server, now I'm using Java EE in Netbeans to make a simple Hello World application, and it keeps giving me this error:

```
org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda.debuggerstartexception : connection Refused
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a debug there? Looks like the weblogic server in the given domain has no JPDA port enabled or the port you are using does not match the one configured in the server.

If you just want to run the hello world test, don't use debug

Comment: @mdrg thanks that is so useful, but in this case I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 Which I can't find these thing! I means the remote debugging!